# Is receiving connection in peerjs a blocking action?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

If for example I want to wait for another peer to connect with `peer.on('connection', connect)` does it mean that I will be stuck on this instruction until another peer connects?

Comment: what the library do you use?

Comment: @VadimHulevich peerjs

Answer (score 0):

Well if i correctly understand, you don't stuck, because only limit what you have it's a upload and download limit.

> Data sent between the two peers do not touch any other servers, so the
>   connection speed is limited only by the upload and download rates of
>   the two peers. This also means you don't have the additional latency
>   of an intermediary server.

[Docs](https://peerjs.com/docs.html)